# 2018 Dodge Journey Alarm System

Tags: dodge, wiring, alarm, security, remote-start

I recently bought a new vehicle and had an audio shop put an alarm system and a remote start in the vehicle.

Everything seems to be working just fine, except for an annoyance with the remote start feature.

If I start the vehicle via remote start, it turns over just fine. I can enter the vehicle and put it into drive and go. However, when I start the car with this method, the vehicle brings up a message saying that the car is not in park, while I am driving..

As soon as I stop and put the car in park, it tells me there are no keys in the vehicle.

I took the vehicle back to the shop today and had them check the programming on it and they said everything looked fine and that they are going to research the problem.

I just wanted to see if anyone had experience with alarm systems that might have a better understanding of what is going on?

Here is a link to the alarm/remote start that was installed: https://www.viper.com/car/securityremotestart/product/5305v/viper-entry-level-lcd-2-way-security-and-remote-start-system

Comment: Something was not installed correctly. Let the shop solve it.

Comment: @Moab - that’s why I took it back today after the first install last week. They looked again and blamed it being “too new” that the manufacturer must have changed something. I can’t leave my vehicle with them while they try and find out what’s wrong. Was just trying to find out if such issue is common and can maybe pass something along for them to try.

Comment: That is what they do for a living, I doubt anyone here would know. I wish you best of luck solving it.

Comment: @Moab - Oh ye of little faith.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ok smarty pants guide him on how to fix it.

Comment: @Moab - Why are you such a naysayer? Give people on here a chance to answer the question. It might not be able to be answered because of the lack of information. But give it a chance. Someone may surprise you.